# No se genera fichero de error siempre

Tags: java

necesito que me genere un archivo de error siempre que conecte a hola, pero no me los genera siempre solo a veces... no encuentro el fallo la verdad y tampoco se cuando no se genera el archivo ,el código no es mío , me lo han pasado pasado, os adjunto la función que debería de hacerlo

```
      response = new JSONObject(responseContent.toString());
        //System.out.println(response.toString());            
        if (responseContent.toString().contains("Hash")) {
            
            result = response.getString("shortHashTransaccion");
        } else {
        }
        String datosLlamada = "Ruta llamada: " + URL_addapta_contingencia + "\r\n";
        datosLlamada += "Datos enviados:\r\n" + datos + "\r\n";
        datosLlamada += "conexión establecida: " + status + "\r\n";
        datosLlamada += "Datos recibidos:\r\n" + responseContent.toString();
        ErrorLogger.writeLogToFile("llamadaAPI", datosLlamada);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ErrorLogger.writeLogToFile("com", ex.toString());
        Logger.getLogger(ConexionBDClientesAPI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        ErrorLogger.writeMissingDonationToFile(numDonation, datos, numDonation, importe, config, mediador);
    } finally {
        connection.disconnect();
    }
    
    if("".equals(result)) // el string vacio aqui no se que funcion hace
    {
    } else {
        ErrorLogger.writeMissing480DonationToFile(numDonation, failedRequests, numDonation, importe, config, mediador);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Sin poder ver el código de `ErrorLogger` es un poco complicado saber qué está pasando. Qué hacen los métodos a los que llamas? Y si es código de tu trabajo, cuidado con compartirlo así sin más...

Comment: ErrorLogger crea el archivo en el sitio indicado, es  un proyecto de la universidad

Comment: Agrega el código de `ErrorLogger` a la pregunta, puedes editarla haciendo click aquí [edit]